# I am frustrated because I keep on making mistakes on new job

Tags: new-job, united-states, quitting, productivity

So I am currently a full-time college student and I am also working 2 days a week because I wanna help my parents and also make my own money. So, recently I have been hired in a new workplace (cheesecake store) thanks to my friend who recommended me.

However, the problem is that in this new workplace, my manager keep on telling me to work faster, and improve my performance but so far I just worked 4 days in this new place and I keep on getting frustrated and mad at myself (whenever I do a mistake such as cutting the cake badly or not doing it well enough) up to the point that I am thinking about quitting.

Although my manager is very kind and easygoing, I can tell by his face and expression that he is getting frustrated and losing his patience because he have to train not only me, but many other new employees. However, my peers seems to be doing way better than I am at cutting the cakes and overall.

However, my only problem is not that I am making mistake, but also because I kept on being told that I work too slow but I am really trying my best to work as fast as I can while also doing it well I even skip my lunch during those 4 days so that I would try to catch on everything during that time. So, whenever I hear that I am working too slow I get even more frustrated at myself because even though I am trying my best, I feel like it is still not enough.

I've had 2 jobs before this one and I have never been told that I work slow nor did I do much mistakes or mistakes at all when being trained. I am really good at being proactive. But, even so, I do not think this is going to help me be a good worker in this new job. *I really need some advice as what should I do, or what strategies can I take to improve this situation?*

I am thinking about quitting, but I also feel bad for my friend because she was the one that helped me get into this job. Also, whenever I finish my shift, I get out very frustrated and disappointed at my self up to the point that is hard for me to do my homework and study for my classes after work. I really feel so useless and stupid right now.

Comment: Every job has its learning curve, you just started that particular work (4 days very few time working there) so it is natural that you struggle a bit to learn your way in the job. Are other employees also just starting? Most probably not, so it is also natural they are better at it by now. Also, if you want to quit you don't have to feel bad for your friend, as in now way are you harming him/her by quitting.

Comment: @GrayCygnus - actually, if youngstudent was recommended by a friend, and then flakes out, the friend does lose credibility with the boss.  So there is a harm.  It's not horrible, but it shouldn't be totally discounted either.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek I believe that it would harm the friend if the OP left the company in bad terms. Quitting given the OP did not find the company a good fit for him (or him not fitting in the company) is understandable in some cases, as it would be for the OP to have rejected the offer in the beginning (he is in his rights to reject, no hard feelings for not taking the job or quitting gracefully).

Comment: @youngstudent Took an edit to your question, removing some minor errors and improving it a bit. I also expanded your actual question so it is more on topic. If you feel it should be further edited please go ahead. Welcome to The Workplace BTW :)

Comment: @GrayCygnus Yes I agree with you, however it feels like my manager is expecting me to catch on everything fast as he is constantly reminding me that I have to be faster(even when I have to cut the cakes). So, when I see the other new employees doing it better it makes me feel that I am the one who is wrong for not catching up everything faster. As you said, they have been working 1 week longer than me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, 4 days is not very long at all.  The other new workers are also new, but at this point have twice as much experience as you do.  So the first thing to do is quit beating yourself up about this.  By dragging yourself down, you are making it harder to do well in this job and in the rest of your life.  Do as well as you can and then let it go.

However, any time you think you could be doing better in a job but are struggling with what and how, a good option is to talk to the boss and ask for specific ways to improve.  So say something like this:

> Boss, I know I'm really new at this, but it seems like you expect me to catch on a lot faster than I am, and to do better work.  Can you give me some specific ideas for how you think I can do this job better?  Since I'm new, maybe we can start with something simple, like cutting the cake better and consistently.  I'm frustrated that I seem to be doing so poorly, and I'm open to suggestions for how I can improve.

It's possible that the boss is just being careless, and expecting you to be working at the same level as much more experienced workers, and asking him for specific help will remind him of your newness.  With any luck, he'll ask give you some useful hints, because every job does take some specific skills that need to be learned.  And this shows that you are willing and want to improve.

Answer (score 1):

I was at your position too back when I was a fresh graduate.

I offer you this: keep at it, and get good.

Being accepted at your work means that there are qualities that management sees in you that they value. They believe that you can contribute some good to the company, be it your enthusiasm, your desire to improve, the way you smile and interact with customers/guests, etc.

Unless suggested or explicitly told so by a higher up, just keep at it.. BUT focus on "getting good" as well.

Make a point to improve your cake cutting skills even at home, don't let the manager repeat himself, wash dishes spic and span (assuming it's a part of your role)

Do it not only to prove to management you have what it takes, but to prove to yourself as well that you're not a quitter.